# jQuery : append or replace automatic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, append

```
################## SIMPLIFIED VERSION  ##################
```

What I need:

```
$('body').appendOrReplace('<div id="foo"></div>')
```

The first time, the result is :

```
<body><div id="foo"></div></body>
```

Now, if I re-run the same code, the result should not change!

If there is any child in the DOM to append like `$('body').appendOrReplace('<div id="foo"><p id="bar"></p></div>')`, appendOrReplace must just take the id of first element.

The problem is : the argument is a string (not a dom), so I can't get easily the id, to test if already exist.

```
################## MY USE CASE (EDIT)  ##################
```

I use template JST (with Rails), so I have this code :

```
$('#page').append(app.JST('path/to/template'));
```

JST template can return a full page of html (a very long string of future HTML).

I need to ensure unicity of template. Each template begin by an element with an unique ID.

So I need a method jquery to append this full DOM if and only if the element not exist, or replace if already exist.

Comment: You can create DOM element with jQuery and get `id`: `$('<div id="foo"><p id="bar"></p></div>').attr('id')`

Comment: if my string is a very long string with lot of DOM (like in my case, I use template JST), it's not a good idea to create jquery element just to get id.

Answer (score 3):

You just need like this:

```
if ($("#foo").length == 1)
  // Replace
else
  // Append
```

You can create a function like this:

```
$.fn.appendOrReplace = function (param) {
  // do that
}
```

And the next thing you can do is:

```
var contentFoo = '<div id="foo"></div>';

if ($("#foo").length == 1)
  $('body').replaceWith(contentFoo);
else
  $('body').append(contentFoo);
```

Comment: @Matrix Can you please clarify? What are you trying to do? I will surely get you a solution. Sorry for not understanding the question.

Comment: I agree but the question is : how I do this function^^

Comment: @Matrix Give me some time buddy I will make that function and post.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet from the other answer did not work for me.

This one is working:

```
if ($("#foo").length > 0)
  $('#foo').replaceWith('<div id="foo">updated</div>');
else
  $('body').append('<div id="foo">initial</div>');
```